# firebase authentication rest API request with axios

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, axios

I am trying to write function to Sign in user with Email and Password.

Using Axios and firebase rest API.

So this is how Axios instance looks like, really simple right? ...

```
 const authUrl = `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=${DATABASE_SECRET}`;
const baseURL = "https://beauty-wonderland-e913c-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com";

export const getAxios = (token = null) => {
  const config = {
    baseURL: baseURL,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
        "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With",
    },
    timeout: 10000,
  };

  if (token !== null) {
    // config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;

    config.baseURL = authUrl;
    config.withCredentials = true;

  }

  let instance = axios.create(config);

  instance.interceptors.request.use(
    (request) => {
      return request;
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log("axios error: ", error);
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );

  instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response;
  });

  return instance;
};
```

This code works fine, flexible and can send any kind of request, but when it comes to authentication, there is problem with sending user data: email and password.

```
const loginHandler = async () => {
    const response = await getAxios("/").post("", {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: "example@example.com",
        password: "password",
        returnSecureToken: true,
      }),
    });

    const outPut = processResponse(response);

    console.log(outPut);
}
```

so as i guess There is problem with this part

```
{
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: "a@a.com",
            password: "123456",
            returnSecureToken: true,
          }),
        });
 }
```

if fetch function works this way

```
fetch(   
`https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPasswordkey=${DATABASE_SECRET}`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: "example@example.com",
          password: "password",
          returnSecureToken: true,
        }),
      }
    );
```

why do axios gives following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest at ... from origin 'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Please note other get and post request with axios works, and alo authentication works with fetch, only axios shows such an error, please post additional resourses to learn more about firebase rest API and Axios usecases.

This is how error looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The baseURL in the axios instance returned by "getAxios" function is `https://beauty-wonderland-e913c-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com` and not the Auth REST API url. It should be `authUrl` instead. While in fetch you have hard-coded the URL so the URL is correct for sure.

**Edit:**

Remove those extraneous headers. You just need content-type as per the docs. I got the same CORS error when I had those.

```js
const config = {
    baseURL: baseURL,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    timeout: 10000,
  };
```

Comment: <code> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[TOP_SECRET]/' from origin 'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. <code>

This is an error, so there is correct url there and this code should make sence

     <code>config.baseURL = authUrl;</code>

Comment: @BekaBatmanashvili could you share a screenshot of your console with the error?

Comment: edited post, uploaded image, I hope quality is good enough, if you alos need to know what is in ```headers: { Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Authorization: [top_SECRET]
Content-Type: "application/json"}```

Comment: @BekaBatmanashvili you need to remove those extra headers. Check updated answer.